# how do i initialize public static list to have atleast one Person before i can manually add more employees to the list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been struggling to initialize my public static list myListPerson.

I would like to have one person in my list who is the admin every time I run the ASP.NET MVC project.

I'm not sure what i did wrong in my code,please help point out my error when trying to initialize my public list.

Below is my controller;

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // holds all new people registered in system in this list
    public static List<Person> myListPerson = new List<Person>();
    Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
    Employee myEmployee = new Employee();

    // incremental customer number for ViewCustomer
    int Cus_Number = 1000;

    public ActionResult ViewCustomer(string Name, string Surname, string Email, int Cell, int IDNumber)
    {
        Cus_Number = Cus_Number + 1;
        myCustomer.Name = Name;
        myCustomer.Surname = Surname;
        myCustomer.Email = Email;
        myCustomer.Cell = Cell;
        myCustomer.IDNumber = IDNumber;
        myCustomer.CustomerID = "Cus" + Cus_Number;
        myListPerson.Add(myCustomer);

        return View(myListPerson);
    }

    // GET: Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // I tried set admin values here but it still does not 
        // work when I check my view which displays people in list
        myEmployee.Name = "1";
        myEmployee.Surname = "1";
        myEmployee.Email = "1";
        myEmployee.Cell = 0;
        myEmployee.IDNumber = 0;
        myEmployee.EmployeeID = "Emp" + 1000;
        myListPerson.Add(myEmployee);
        return View(myListPerson);
}
```

Below is my view shows my list of employee

```
@model List<FurryFeista.ViewModels.Person>

@using FurryFeista.ViewModels;

<table id="employeetable">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Employee Surname</th>
                <th>Employee ID Number</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Email Adress</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Person i in Model)
            {
                if (i is Employee)
                {
                    Employee user = (Employee)i;
                    <tr>
                        <td>@user.EmployeeID</td>
                        <td>@user.Name</td>
                        <td>@user.Surname</td>
                        <td>@user.IDNumber</td>
                        <td>@user.Cell</td>
                        <td>@user.Email</td>
                        <td>@user.Username</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is your list static? Als please describe what error you are getting. But first try to remove the static part.